# Set SQL Server 2008 R2 as a prerequisites while making a C# set up file

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have developed a C# desktop application. I need to deploy it in a client's machine. This app needs SQL Server 2008 R2. It is not feasible to set up SQL Server first and then my app. So, I thought of giving dependencies. Unfortunately the prerequisites option in VS has no option to include SQL Server 2008 R2.

[image]

It has only option for SQL Server 2005 Express and SQL Server 2008 Express.

How do I include SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server 2005 express and Sql Server 2008 express come with below Limitation  :

1. uses only 1 CPU
2. can use max of 1 GB of RAM
3. is limited to 10 GB of database size

you can use these software for individual system (desktop).

But Sql Server 2008 R2 is dedicated database server ,you can install it same system or separate system.

you need to write custom code for pre-detection Sql Server 2008 R2 Instance.
Below link would be helpful :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database